# ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve sdk.chat:firebase-app:5.1.1

Tags: android, gradle

I am getting :app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve sdk.chat:firebase-app:5.1.1 error again and again. Please help me.

Comment: Please share more details on the project setup and configuration file.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.